# Android Studio without Java

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opengl-es, android-ndk

I would like to use Android Studio for a C++/OpenGL NDK project but I do not want to have Oracle's Java installed on my computer, as it is a security risk. Is there anyway to use this IDE without ever installing Java?

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio itself relies on Java, so it is not possible to run Android Studio without a JVM.

Most of the weaknesses in java, are related to running untrusted code.  This is a significant problem when the browser plugin is enabled, but without the browser plugin, the language attack surface is significantly smaller.

Comment: I disabled the browser plugin initially, and later found somehow it got RE-ENABLED. Very worrisome! I decided to wipe my Mac and reinstall macOS to be safe.

Comment: On the Mac the java settings in the System Settings indicate whether browser support is enabled or not. It is not per-browser.

Answer (score 0):

No you should have JDK to use NDK inside of android studio

how ever you can develop android apps with xamarin in visual studio using c++ language...
also in android studio 3 you can use kotlin language for developing but thats preview version.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio comes with integrated JRE (OpenJDK) and can run without installing standalone Oracle Java

BUT I don't know how it is about C++ support with it, as you need java headers